# How to not use accountchooser.com with google-identity-toolkit question

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

We've been using google identity toolkit for our login on our alpha and beta site, and it's been smooth, simple, and easy to do (Alpha and beta users were given specific login instructions).  When we left beta we noticed that 100% of new visitors we lose at sign-up / sign-in.  So we started asking why.
  100% of our new users do not trust the login system.  They feel like it is "spamy feeling" and "not the same site."  This is because it goes to the accountchooser.com.  We do have our custom graphics and welcome information, so it is still branded, but alas, they do not like it.
  So my question is, is it possible to use google identity toolkit and never to leave our site?  Or should we drop google identity toolkit for something like google signin or something direct from OpenID Foundation / OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to disable accountchooser.com from the sign in/up flow, pass the following key/value pair in the config object for window.google.identitytoolkit.start:

```
accountChooserEnabled: false
```

However we do not recommend disabling accountchooser.com, as it adds more friction in the sign in process. When an account is saved in ac.com, a returning user can simply click the saved account in ac.com and sign in with basically one click. Disabling ac.com will force returning users to type in their previously registered emails. In some cases, they may have to go through the forgot password flow as they may have forgotten their previously saved email.